# Netflix in surround sound?

Tags: sound, netflix

Is there a way to get 5.1 Surround Sound in Netflix? I have it working for other media already, so the surround sound drivers are fine (pulseaudio etc), but Netflix plays in stereo. Works fine on Windows & MacOS (this is a Triple Boot desktop system)

Using Ubuntu 18.10 & Firefox or Chrome to play netflix via the web app.

Answer (score 2):

"5.1 surround sound is not currently supported while streaming on a computer using Microsoft Silverlight or HTML5. However, it is supported in the Netflix app for Windows 8 and Windows 10."

From [here](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/14163).

Comment: There was a PPA for the wine port of the windows desktop app, but the PPA no longer works in Ubuntu 18. I wonder if someone could port that and get it to work